# Pilcrow Removing Regex Formula in Open Office no longer works even though it used to.

Tags: regex, apache

To remove Pilcrows from my Open Office file, I was taught to check off 1) Match case and 2) Regular expressions In the Search box for the Alternate Open Office Find and Replace and then type: ([a-z ])\p([a-z ]) in Find box.  Then in  the Replace box type: \1\2 .
This used to work to get rid of most of the Pilcrows in my Open Office text, but now it suddenly stopped working and won't replace Pilcrows any more. Now it only says "Not Found". How can I make it work again, and why is this formula so erratic?  Thank you. I'm a newby. Today is June 13, 2014.